# (Proof) Representing preorder $\succsim$ as a real-valued function.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, relations, economics

I am reading a proof and having a hard time understanding on some parts.

In math language, the proof is trying to show the existence of continuous preorder $\succsim$ (i.e. preserved under limits, complete, transitive) on $X\subset\mathbb{R^L_+}$ as a real-valued function.

Im economics language, want to show rational and continuous preference relation on $X\subset\mathbb{R^L_+}$ can be represented as real-valued utility function. (Reference: Micro Theory MWG Ch.3)

Here's the part I have a question on:

> Show for every bundle $x\in X\subset\mathbb{R^L_+}$, $\exists$ nonnegative real scalar $k$ such that $k(x)e\sim x$ where $e=(1,...,1)$.

Strategy for Proof:

> Know $\succsim$ is continuous on X. So the upper contour and lower contour (i.e. $U(x)=\{y\in X:y\succsim x\}$, $L(x)=\{y\in X:x\succsim y\}$) are closed. Then, $K^+=\{k\in\mathbb{R}:ke\succsim x\}$, $K^-=\{k\in\mathbb{R}:x\succsim ke\}$ are also nonempty and closed. By completeness of $\succsim$, $\mathbb{R_+}\subset(K^+\cup K^-)$. With all the above with the fact that $\mathbb{R_+}$ is connected, there is some nonnegative real number $k$ such that $k(x)e\sim x$.

My questions are:

> - Why does completeness of $\succsim$ imply the set of $K^+,K^-$ is the cover of the nonnegative real line?
> - Is $\mathbb{R_+}=(K^+\cup K^-)$ also true?
> - Why is it not obvious that $K^+,K^-$ from the beginning? Suppose $X\subset\mathbb{R_+}$ so $x$ is just a real number. $e$ will be 1. then, isn't it obvious that $K^+=\{k\in\mathbb{R}:ke\geq x\}$, $K^-=\{k\in\mathbb{R}:x\geq ke\}$ are nonempty and closed **AND their intersection is the point $x$**? I don't understand why the authors of the proof goes over these hoops of cover, connectedness of $\mathbb{R_+} and so forth to prove this.

If anything is unclear, please comment. I will try my best to clarify, and appreciate your 2 cent and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pre-order being complete has no topological meaning, but purely set-theoretic. It means that for any two points $x,y$ in the domain of the pre-order, we must have $x \succsim y$ or $y \succsim x$ (or possibly both here, because we have a pre-order, so we can have both at the same time (invariant goods (?), or some such thing, economics is not my field, though I did do some of it).

Look at the definitions, where $x$ is now fixed for the rest of the proof (and $x \in X$, the domain of $\succsim$): $K^+ = \{k \in \mathbb{R}: ke \succsim x\}$ and $K^- = \{k \in \mathbb{R}: x \succsim ke \}$. So we look at all scalars $k$, compute $ke$ where $e = (1,1,\ldots)$ and compare it to the fixed point $x$, using the preference relation $\succsim$. Now as $\succsim$ is complete we must have that at least one of $x \succsim ke$ or $ke \succsim x$ holds, and we put $k$ into $K^+$ when the one thing happens, and in $K^-$ when the other thing happens, and in both if both happen. *If* we know that $ke$ is in $X$ for every $k$, we would know that $\mathbb{R} = K^+ \cup K^-$. But I think that in these kinds of economic settings, $X$ is a subset of the positive vectors in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{L}$, and $X$ is the domain of the ordering $\succsim$, so in this case I think that te assumption on $X$ is that we do know that $ke \in X$ for every positive $k$, but not necessarily for every $k$. So we can, in that case, only say that $\mathbb{R}^+ \subseteq K^+ \cup K^-$, and cannot say about the other $k$, as we do not know that $ke$ is even in $X$, so that comparison with $x$ is defined.

A special case of the reals does not show anything. The whole point is that $X$ can be *any* subset (often closed and convex though, and not quite arbitrary) and $\succsim$ any relation satisfying some conditions. The theory is to find the most general, useful, conditions that will guarantee some interesting theorems on $X$. Taking a trivial special case defeats the whole purpose. Here we can, from just saying it's complete (which is part of being a rational preference, IIRC) etc. we can prove things about the relation $\succsim$. So we need to use general facts about connectedness etc. to do that. The connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^+$ and the closedness of $K^+$ and $K^-$ (which follows from $\succsim$ being "continuous") is all that's needed to find a point in $K^+ \cap K^-$ which is the $k(x)$ that is calimed to exist.

I suggest trying other relations (like the lexicographic order) in the plane etc. to get a feel for what more general $\succsim$ relations can look like. If you use a good text (I don't know yours) this would have been done at the beginning, to motivate the whole theory in the first place. That's what I would do, anyway.

Comment: Henno, thanks for the response. Let me think about this hard and come back, comment :)

Comment: First, thanks for making things more clear. I gained clarity. One point of clarification from what I haven't said clear is : $k\in\mathbb{R_+}$, X, the domain of $\succsim$, is $\mathbb{R^L_+}$. Hence, $ke\in X$ for all $k\in\mathbb{R_+}$ meaning $\mathbb{R_+}=(K^+\cup K^-)$. But on intuitive level, it does make sense like you explained. Because $\succsim$ is a complete preorder on $X=\mathbb{R^L_+}$, the positive scalar $k$ has to fall in the set $K^+$ or $K^-$, and this is exactly the union of two sets, coinciding with the definition the set of these two sets being a cover for the real line.

Answer (score 0):

Rader (Review of Economic Studies, 1963) provided conditions for a preference relation $\succeq$ to be representable by an upper semi-continuous function, and Debreu (1954 in a volume, 1964 in International Economic Review) provided conditions for the function to be continuous.  These results dispense with the "monotonicity" assumption.  The monotonicity assumption is mainly pedagogical, like in MWG, so that students can visualize how indifference curves are being mapped onto the "diagonal" of the consumption set to create a utility function.

A more general intuition comes from "Archimedean axioms" of the kind: if $x \succ z$, then there exists a $y$ such that $ x \succ y \succ z$. Consider what is (often called) Cantor's Theorem: a chain $D$ is isomorphic with a sub-chain of the chain of real numbers iff $D$ contains a countable, order-dense subset (see also, Birkhoff's book "Lattice Theory" and Nachbin's book "Order and Topology"). If you have an order dense subset (say, all bundles of $\mathbb{R}^N_+$ that are rational-valued), then continuity of the preference relation has a substantial amount of bite. You can construct a utility function using the countable order-dense subset: let $Y \subset X$ be the order dense subset, $y = \{y_\ell\}_{\ell=1}^\infty$ an arbitrary sequence of the points in $Y$, and define
$$
u(x) = \sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^\ell} \mathbb{I}\{x \succeq y_\ell \}.
$$
This is a utilty function for $\succeq$ if $\succeq$ has open lower contour sets, $L(x) = \{y: x \succ y\}$. Many utility representations roughly have a form like this (as an ``average'' over comparisons to a sequence in a countable dense subset).  One of my favorite papers on how this works is by Richter and Wong, in Economic Theory, that is concerned with revealed preference theory and really makes the role of order dense subsets clearer, at least to me. The problem is that the $u(x)$ above isn't necessarily continuous: it is only an ordinal representation, and in particular, the enumeration of $Y$ in the sequence $\{y_\ell\}$ can change the values it takes.  What then?

So consider monotonicity of $\succeq$, along with continuity and completeness. For a continuous preference relation, the sets $\{y: y \succeq x\}$ and $\{y : x \succeq y\}$ must be closed, so the sets $\{y: y \succ x\}$ and $\{y: x \succ y\}$ must be open. Take any $x$, and let $[x] = \{ y: y \succeq x \text{ and } x \succeq y\}$ be the equivalence class of $x$ with respect to $\succeq$ (its indifference curve), and $E = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^N_+ : x = k(1,1,...,1), k \in \mathbb{R}_+\}$. Then $ [x] \cap E$ has exactly one point: it can't have more than one because that would violate transitivity and monotonicity (usually defined strictly, i.e., if $x \ge y$ and $x\neq y$ then $x \succ y$) of $\succeq$. To show there is at least one, since $\succeq$ is monotonic, there is a bundle $q^+ \succ x$ and another bundle $x \succ q^-$, with $q^+, q^- \in E$, with corresponding scalar values $k^+$ and $k^-$ --- just take $k^+$ so large that every element is strictly larger than the largest element in $x$, and similarly for $k^-$. 
Consider the closed interval $K = [k^-,k^+]$. Take $k^L = \inf \{k\in K: x\succ k*(1,1,...,1)\}$ and $k^H = \inf \{k\in K: k*(1,1,...,1) \succ x\}$. By monotonicity and transitivity, $k^H \ge k^L$, but suppose $k^H>k^L$. Then there is an open set $J = \{ k \in (k^L, h^H): k*(1,1,...,1) \}$ for which $x \sim J*(1,1,...,1)$ by completeness of $\succeq$ and the definitions of $k^L$ and $k^H$, which is a contradiction of monotonicity and transitivity of $\succeq$. Therefore, $k^L=k^H=k^*$. Map every element of $[x]$ to the scalar $k^*$, and the utility function is $u(x)=k^*([x])$.

What if you don't have monotonicity? Then there is a result called the "Open Gap Lemma".  The idea is that if you have a function $u(x)$ that represents $\succeq$ but is not necessarily continuous, under some circumstances the discontinuities can be removed to yield a continuous function.  This usually applies because a preference relation $\succeq$ imposes certain properties on how the discontinuities behave. The connectedness of $\mathbb{R}$ plays an important role here, which is a topological property, as some of your comments suggest.
At the end of the day, monotonicity is a distraction from the real issues. The correct proof of the open gap lemma is in Debreu 1964, and there are easier proofs available since then.

Try reading Efe Ok's "Real Analysis with Economic Applications" alongside MWG or whatever if you know too much math to read MWG with a clear conscience.